# Conditionally Show BootStrap Modal

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I get this error

```
Uaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

and the line that it shows the error on is here

```
$('#validateVisit').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
     document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = e.relatedTarget.id;
});
```

but if I add a `Console.Log(e.relatedTarget.id);` I get a value so I don't think that is actually the error

My JQuery and my HTML are as below:

```
async function visitModification(id, type) {
    let title = null;
    if (type == "manager") { title = "Input Data For Manager Validation"; }
    if (type == "employee") { title = "Input Data For Employee Validation"; }
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&plugin=ValidationData&format=raw&id=" + id + "&type=" + type,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#validationModal .modal-body p').html(data);
            jQuery("#editModalTitle").html(title);
            jQuery('#validationModal').modal('show');
        },
        error(xhr, status, error) { alert("There is a problem in server, please try later"); }
    });
}


<div id="validationModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 id="editModalTitle" class="modal-title">h</h4>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Form</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><button id="validateModalSave" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save</button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and thro the debugging I can do I have confirmed that the error is thrown when the code reaches the JQuery inside the `success: function(data) {` bc if I comment out the 3 lines there no error is displayed (but of course the modal I want to dispaly isn't displayed either).

What do I need to do to resolve this?